# Can't get access to data sent from a server as POST AJAX in JSON

Tags: json, ajax, go

I have a form on a page. I send an ajax json POST request which I want to parse on a server. I'm using no Go frameworks.

```
type data1 struct {
  email string
  fullName string `json:full_name`
  body string
}


  //[...............]
  var d1 data1
  err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&d1)
  if err != nil {
    log.Print("error#1")
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
  }

  log.Printf("data#1: %+v", d1)
```

I always get this in the log:

```
  data#1: {email: fullName: body:}
```

From a server a requect gets sent correctly -- I see that in Chrome dev tools.

Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `data1` struct the fields are not exported. They must be exported to use in json decoder. Also, your `json` tag is not written in valid syntax.

You can change the `data1` struct like following:

```golang
type data1 struct {
  Email string
  FullName string `json:"full_name"`
  Body string
}
```

[Go PlayGround Link](https://play.golang.org/p/xV77lEsASwO)

Comment: works. Is there a way to not introduce a named struct for that? Via an anonymous one?

Comment: In your example there's no 'map' used. How?